# ProtoBuf.NET - Choose fields you want to load at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, linq, protobuf-net

We are using ProtoBuf.NET to serialize our report to file (using DataContract/DataMember attributes to mark up the fields we are interested in). Is there any way (at runtime) to mark which fields we want to Deserialize back ?

We need this feature because we are dealing with large data (1Mln rows with 250+ rows of data). and depending on linq query we run against it, want only to load/populate fields which are required (to save memory footprint mainly).

Yes, we are using IEnum way of retrieving data, but if you are doing any GroupBy in your linq, it tries to load everything which is causing OutOfMem (because of too many fields in it).

Comment: GroupBy always "load everything", independently of where the data came from. Consider writing a replacement that does not keep all items that have been grouped but eagerly aggregates them.

Comment: @usr, that's the next thing we are trying to improve. we already cut the memory by half and improve performance 5x!! but have you got any ideas/libs you have used maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there *is*, but...

```
var model = RuntimeTypeModel.Create();
var metaType = model.Add(typeof(Foo), false);
if(includeA) metaType.Add(1, "A");
//...
if(includeXYZ) metaType.Add(42, "XYZ");
var foo = (Foo)model.Deserialize(source, typeof(Foo));
```

but note that this will cause it to do all the assembly generation etc per `RuntimeTypeModel` instance - you would probably want to cache a model per field subset. This could be quite easy if your choice of fields is via a `[Flags]` enum, as you could just use a `Dictionary<YourFields, RuntimeTypeModel>`

Comment: tnx Mark, will it work using IEnum retrieval we got? i.e.: Serializer.DeserializeItems<T>(stream, PrefixStyle.Base128, fieldNumber). i.e. how do i pass that RuntimeModel back to Deserialiser?

Comment: @anvarbekraupov you don't; `Serializer.*` is actually just a short-cut to `RuntimeTypeModel.Default.*`. You use the `DeserializeItems` etc methods *on the custom model instead* - i.e. `model.DeserializeItems<Foo>(...)`

Comment: @anvarbekraupov more specifically, `Serializer.*` dates back to v1, where there was no concept of custom models - so the `Serializer.*` methods were retained as convenience tools to make it painless to change version - especially since most people *never need to know about custom models*

Comment: it worked! reduced our linq from 102 sec to 18, along with peak mem drop from 3.9Gb to 2.1Gb! quite an improvement for 5 lines of code! ;) tnx mate for quick guidence on this